# python not appending to each line in file in directory

Tags: python

I am trying to append a string (`"testing123"`) to each line of every file in my current working directory (`cache/configs`). This is what I've done:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir('cache/configs'):
    with open('cache/configs/'+file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line+"testing123"
```

The command goes through without error, but nothing is changing. At face value my logic seems cogent. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

[Python version 3.6]

Answer (score 3):

You're never saving the change.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir('cache/configs'):
    with open('cache/configs/'+file, "r+") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            lines[i] = line.rstrip()+"testing123"
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: readlines would still have the \n, when you do a + "testing123" it would add it after the \n,

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import os

for file in os.listdir('cache/configs'):
    cmd = "sed -i -e 's/$/ testing123/' cache/configs/{}".format(file)
    os.system(cmd)
```